# Java Discord bot, @mention a user?

Tags: java, discord

There doesn't seem to be much about this on google aside from advising to use their userID (a string of numbers) instead of their name.

I enabled dev mode to grab their ID and tried the below however it just comes out as a plain text message with no @mention.

```
chan.sendMessage("Hey @299059199160352768 are you there?").queue();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add an opening and closing angle bracket. `<@id>`. So your string would look like

```
chan.sendMessage("Hey <@299059199160352768> are you there?").queue();
```